# What is the Firefox repository with all dependencies solved?

Tags: linux, fedora, firefox

I'm using Fedora Core 3, and Firefox needs to be upgraded from version 2.0 to some advanced version, such as 3.0 or 3.6. I used the `remi` repository for `yum` command, but that repository doesn't contain any other dependencies for Firefox v 3.6.

What Fedora repositories can Firefox be installed from with all other dependencies?

Comment: Why go through so much pain? Why not upgrade to a later Fedora? You are over 10 releases behind. I'm just curious.

Comment: In my office they still use that godforsaken machine with that antique os. When that OS boots it displays `Booting fedora Core 2.6` then after sometime the screen says `Redhat nash 4.1` and after when i get to the desktop I could see the RedHat Screen only. Now tell me this is'nt interesting :-). Could you tell any repo @Tshepang

Comment: It would be faster and easier to secretly install the latest Fedora.

Comment: How to install latest fedora @Keith ? It would be playing pretty close to the chest. I just want firefox only. Not entire OS upgrade. mmmm need a good repository....thats all

Comment: The problem is that once you follow the entire dependency chain you may have a whole new OS anyway. I don't find a pre-built binary for that combination. Maybe you can compile it from source.

Comment: okay @keith i shall try it to compile from the source tarball

Comment: Why don't you just download Firefox from original provider and run from your home dir? I think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah thats what ive been trying to do. But when compiling that also emits the error that some package missing....It my fate that I stuck up with this poor old fedora.

Comment: Fedora Core 3? Please, please stop. The distribution hasn't gotten security updates for over five years. There are so many known root exploits that it isn't even funny. Pull that sucker off the Internet _now_, please, for the good of the world.

Comment: Taking your question title literally, I'd answer “it's Fedora Core 14”. If you must use an old distribution, you'll have to resign yourself to either using the old programs in the distribution or recompiling everything (i.e. upgrading your whole distribution save perhaps for the kernel). It would be easier to run a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got to get this out of the way first:

You really, really need to turn off that system. Security updates haven't been released for it for over five years — and, what's more, that release is from back in the dark ages when the project hadn't really gotten off the ground.

If you must keep it similar, moving to CentOS 5 will give you an only slightly updated set of software but with current updates and some lifecycle left to go.

All that said, if I were forced at gunpoint, the thing I'd try is downloading the non-rpm-packaged tarball of Firefox directly from [mozilla](https://www.mozilla.com/). It may be that the system is still too old for that, but I think it's your best bet.

Well, fourth best bet, behind upgrading to Fedora 15, upgrading CentOS 5, or just throwing the system in a dumpster.

Comment: I'd upvote this again and again, if I could.

Comment: yea @mattdm i had picked up the 4th point you have said, and tried. But no luck mate. Most of the libraries are need to be changed. It aint gonna work. Gonna giveup the hope for firefox :(  Can I use other browsers like opera 10 or 11 though?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what other people have answered here.  Better to just upgrade.

You'll have a hard time running a newer firefox on such an old OS.  You'll have to upgrade major parts of the OS just to get the more recent Firefox to compile, because it depends on APIs from more recent versions of gtk, gdk, libstdc++, etc.  You're pretty much going to be upgrading the core OS at that point.

If you really must use such old versions of software, you might be able to get away with using RHEL4 or CentOS4, which has about a year more life in it before it is unsupported.